# Different ways of setting a state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone tell the difference between setting these State variables in a component?
Is there going to be any difference re-rendering while setting it?

```
function handleData(e){
    inputData[e.target.name]= e.target.value
    setInputData({...inputData})
    console.log(setInputData)
}
function handleData(e){
    inputData[e.target.name]= e.target.value
    setInputData(inputData)
}
function handleData(e){
    setInputData(...inputData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value)
}
```

I have tried to  use the spread operators in different ways here, can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Are you sure this is TypeScript? I don't see any types anywhere and without them you'll get compiler errors.  If you don't care about types then you might want to untag "TypeScript".  If you do then please [edit] the code here to be a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about *without* unrelated errors.

Comment: Since we don't actually know what `setInputData` does (assuming a set method from `useState`) we cannot say what the code does for certain. Assuming it is the setter method for `inputData` then the first method simply updates input data based on the event name and value then logs to console, the second does the same thing without the log, and the third does the same thing in a single line. When managing state in react it is not sufficient to simply update an object directly. You should use the state setter method to trigger the appropriate state reflections in react.

Comment: The last one is a syntax error. Did you mean to add `{` and `}` around the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to change the state of some components. Based on this, following is a full code to explain the problem.

```
const App = () => {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = React.useState({
    firstName: '',
    middleName: '',
    lastName: ''
  })
  // Using useEffect hook to log inputData instead of logging inside the handler function.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('inputData', inputData)
  })
  function handleData(e) {
    inputData[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    setInputData({ ...inputData }) // spreads out properties of InputData object
    console.log(setInputData) // setInputData is just a function
  }

  function handleData(e) {
    inputData[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    setInputData(inputData)
    console.log(setInputData) // setInputData is just a function
  }

  function handleData(e) {
    setInputData({ ...inputData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  return (
    <div id='app'>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleData(e)} >
        <input name='firstName' onChange={handleData} type='text' value={inputData.firstName} /><br />
        <input name='middleName' onChange={handleData} type='text' value={inputData.middleName} /><br />
        <input name='lastName' onChange={handleData} type='text' value={inputData.lastName} /><br />
        <input name='longName' onChange={handleData} type='text' value={inputData.longName || ''} /><br />

        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <p>FirstName: {inputData.firstName}</p>
        <p>FirstName: {inputData.middleName}</p>
        <p>LastName: {inputData.lastName}</p>
        <p>LongName: {inputData.longName}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The first one is creating a new object using `spread(...)` operator by copying existing state. This is the recommended approach for updating state when dealing with objects in React.This ensures **immutability**. Immutability is a vital concept in react. This blog [Immutability in React](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-react-should-you-mutate-objects/#:%7E:text=An%20immutable%20value%20or%20object,functionality%20to%20undo%20and%20redo.) goes in depth on immutability in react.

The second one **mutates** the inputData state directly which is why there would be **no re-render and should avoid this**. It causes issues with re-rendering and updating UI. Instead, you can create a new object using the spread operator to copy the existing state and then update the new object.

The third one is creating a new object using spread operator, copying existing state and then updating the new object using `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`. It' also a valid way of updating state in React